# Dynamically add legends to matplotlib plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, enthought

I have a set of plots in python and want to add legends to each of them separately. I am generating the plots in a for loop and want to add the legends dynamically.

Im getting only the last legend shown. I want all 9 off them to be displayed

```
for q in range(1,10):
      matplotlib.pylab.plot(s_A_approx, label = q)
matplotlib.pylab.legend(loc = 'upper left')
matplotlib.pylab.show()
```

Comment: To me it's unclear what you're asking.  What do you want to do that the above code doesn't achieve?

Comment: Im not able to get the 9 sets of legends that I need. Im getting just the last one. I even added the statement of

`matplotlib.pylab.hold(True)`

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want the `legend` call *inside* the loop?

Comment: What is the shape of `s_A_approx`?

Comment: No, not trying to call legend inside the loop. And the shape of s_A_approx is an array of 100 numbers ...

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  I had to adjust `label=q` to `label=str(q)`, but after that, the plot and legend are produced as expected.  Maybe see if you can provide here more of your script, like where s_A_approx comes from or an example of what `s_A_approx` looks like?

Comment: A is assembled by a method described in a paper. 

`for q in range(1,10):`
     `A = (A*A.T)**q`
     `[U, s_A_approx, V] = numpy.linalg.svd(A)`
     `matplotlib.pylab.plot(s_A_approx, label = str(q))`
`matplotlib.pylab.legend(loc = 'upper left')`
`matplotlib.pylab.show()`

Comment: and do you get all 9 legends to be shown or only the last one? Im still able to get only the last one..

Comment: Here, I'll post an answer with my setup

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem.  With a few adjustments to your script, what you're expecting is working for me.

```
import matplotlib.pylab
import numpy as np

for q in range(1,10):
    # create a random, 100 length array
    s_A_approx = np.random.randint(0, 100, 100)
    # note I had to make q a string to avoid an AttributeError when 
    # initializing the legend
    matplotlib.pylab.plot(s_A_approx, marker='.', linestyle='None', label=str(q))

matplotlib.pylab.legend(loc='upper left')
matplotlib.pylab.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

---

If it helps, here's my matplotlib version:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'1.0.1'
```