# Use variables in legend handles

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, legend

I want to graph multiple different bar charts and the colors in each graph will vary depending on the data being plotted. I would like to have a legend with handles (to accompany each set of data and provide more detailed information) to make it clear what set of data each color represents.

ex:
I may have two sets of data to plot. I can hardcode that easily (with some help from the patches library):

```
red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color ='red', label='red data')
blue_patch = mpatches.Patch(color ='blue', label='blue data')
ax.legend(handles=[red_patch, blue_patch])
```

[image: Output]

But then in other cases I may want another color or even a few extra colors so the output could look like (in this case, don't need blue):

```
red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color ='red', label='red data')
blue_patch = mpatches.Patch(color ='blue', label='blue data')
yellow_patch = mpatches.Patch(color ='yellow', label='yellow data')
green_patch = mpatches.Patch(color ='green', label='green data')

ax.legend(handles=[red_patch, yellow_patch, green_patch])
```

[image: Output2]

I can define all the colors/handles but it's not really possible to hardcode every possible ax.legend call. That brings me to my question: Can I even use matplotlib handles dynamically?

```
ax.legend(handles=[])
```

I have a corresponding array that tells me which colors I want/need to show but I need a solution on how I can transfer that over for use in handles or a legend.

Comment: Try looking at [Dynamically add legends to matplotlib plots in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264748/dynamically-add-legends-to-matplotlib-plots-in-python?adlt=strict&toWww=1&redig=38956838EF66497584FA338EEAF10DB0).

Comment: Insightful, but I'm plotting using matplotlib.pyplot.barh, in which I call a dataframe just once per graph to plot multiple bars. That solution will just show the first single color.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using *f-string* formating? Using a list of the plot name you just have to retrieve them and add them to the label maybe ?

Comment: Could you add a line of code as an example of your solution?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).